# Зачем нужен трэйт std::common_reference_t?

Tags: c++, traits

Читаю на [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_reference), но не нахожу информации, зачем такая сложная конструкция может использоваться. Может кто объяснить простым языком цель введения этого трэйта и где его использовать?

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59011331/what-is-the-purpose-of-c20-stdcommon-reference